# Mocking Subproces Calls in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pytest

I am trying to use `mock.patch` decorator in the mock library but am having problems. I have this init function where I make two subprocess calls. The first time in `self.setPackageQuota()` and the second time in `self.setBandwidthLimit()`.

```
class User():
    def __init__(self, username, plan, domain, owner, diskQuota, diskUsed):
        self.setUsername(username)
        self.setPlan(plan)
        self.setDomain(domain)
        self.setOwner(owner)
        self.setDiskQuota(diskQuota)
        self.setDiskUsed(diskUsed)
        self.setPackageQuota()
        self.setBandwidthLimit()
```

**self.setPackageQuota()**

```
def setBandwidthLimit(self):
    whmapicall   = subprocess.Popen(["whmapi1" , "showbw", 'searchtype=user', 'search=^%s$' % self.username], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    whmapireturn = whmapicall.stdout.read().split("\n")
    for line in whmapireturn:
```

**self.setPackageQuota()**

```
def setPackageQuota(self):
    whmapicall   = subprocess.Popen(["whmapi1" , "getpkginfo", "pkg=%s" % self.plan], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    whmapireturn = whmapicall.stdout.read().split("\n")
    for line in whmapireturn:
```

I would much rather patch `whmapireturn` to be something else. I also would not like to not run `subprocess.Popen`. My inital thought was to patch out `@mock.patch('subprocess.Popen', MockedClass)` and `@mock.patch('whmapireturn', OtherMockedClass)` but I cant seem to get it to work. How would I test an init fucntion like this while patching out things that I can't have in my enviroment? Thanks in advance for any asistance.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch

Comment: Thanks that was very helpfull.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I comprehend from your question that you want to mock-patch the Subprocess.Popen() call from your file. For that you should use the following approach:-

Let take the scenario where your file name is  for which you want to create the unittest. Therefore:- in the unittest file, you should write:-

```
import library

@mock.patch("library.subprocess")
def test_subprocess_call(mock_subprocess):
    mock_subprocess.Popen.return_value = None
```

I hope you find your answer.

Comment: Thanks that was very helpful.